# C# 8+ Nullable Reference checking: Can Static Analysis work out that either this field or that field is non-null?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

Consider a class with 2 constructors. Let's say that one constructor accepts a dependency, whilst the other accepts a factory for the dependency to be got later:

```
class ThereCanBeOnlyOneButAtLeastOne
{
    readonly Thing? knownThing;
    readonly ThingFactory? factory;
    public ThereCanBeOnlyOneButAtLeastOne(ThingFactory factory) => this.factory = factory;
    public ThereCanBeOnlyOneButAtLeastOne(Thing knownThing) => this.knownThing = knownThing;

    public OtherThing CalculateSomething()
    {
        var theThing = knownThing??factory?.Get();
```

I would like the static analysis to have worked out that theThing is guaranteed NotNull at this point because at least one of the constructors must have been called. But it doesn't.

Can it?

Comment: Note that the type of `theThing` is dependant on the return type of the `Get` method of the factory, make sure it returns a non nullable type.

Comment: indeed it does. Otherwise my question would be flawed :-)

Comment: Static analysis can't really be expected to dive into this rabbit hole. It's the sort of thing that sounds "reasonable" to us but requires non-trivial rules in practice. A simple and in my opinion elegant way of tackling this is to always have only `ThingFactory`, and use a `SameThingFactory` that always returns `knownThing` (or encapsulate both as a delegate, if an entire class is too heavy handed). There are of course other ways of unifying the logic that at least require a null override but once, if it was necessary.

Comment: Note that the mere fact of using `factory?.Get()` is enough to make static analysis think you must know more about the nullability than it does, as it will assume the result might be `null` even with a non-nullable `factory` and even when `knownThing` is not involved at all. The override approach would be `knownThing ?? factory!.Get()`, since "we" know that if `knownThing` is `null`, `factory` must not be (which is also why the use of `?.` is arguably inappropriate here). Note however that this assumption is brittle, and might easily fail if we added another constructor.

Comment: The delegate approach would be `readonly Func<Thing> getThing`, which is assigned as either `() => knownThing` or `factory.Get`. The `knownThing` and `factory` fields then both become optional, and removing them would force methods to use `getThing` (rather than inadvertently using one when the other should have been used). Of course there may be reasons for retaining them (you need to pass them on, or there really is separate logic for a single object rather than a factory).

Comment: agree that `factory!.Get()` is more appropriate that `factory?.Get()` — and is presumably the smallest possible manual 'fix'.  I should have shown example code that just had `factory.Get()`.

Comment: also agree that — if the whole class had more than one method — I'd wrap the access to Thing in a private getThing accessor ( but I shan't in this case because CalculateSomething() method is the only thing the class does and the only access)

Answer (score 0):

The 2021 consensus seems to be: **No, it can't, you have to tell it.**

There is some nearly-relevant functionality in C# 9:

```
    [MemberNotNullWhen(true, nameof(knownThing))]
    [MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(factory))]
    public bool HasKnownThing => knownThing != null;
```

which might lead you to think that

```
var theThing = HasKnownThing ? knownThing : factory.Get();
```

is provably non-null, but the static analysis works out that it doesn't *really know* that factory is non-null:

```
Scratch.cs(38, 38): [CS8775] Member 'factory' must have a non-null value when exiting with 'false'
```

and however you twist, it still comes down to:

The static analysis can't work out for itself that at least one of the fields is non-null, you have to *tell* it. And the minimal way to *tell* it is probably:

```
theThing = knownThing ?? factory!.Get()
```

whether do this in a variable or a field or a private property or method.

Comment: Interesting approach with the `MemberNotNullWhen`. In fact this does work in my installation (that is, `[MemberNotNullWhen(false, nameof(factory))]`, the other one is not necessary/doesn't add anything since the condition already establishes it).

Comment: [Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: :-) copy-pasting your demo I still get the `[CS8775] Member 'factory' must have a non-null value when exiting with 'false'.`  warning? So at this point I feel I can live with, it does a lot but not (yet) everything.

Comment: That's odd because normally Sharplab has the very latest version of the compiler (and it issues no warning), and trying it locally in my Visual Studio (targeting .NET 5, not the preview version) I get no warning either. Maybe you're even further along on the cutting edge where the analyzer has this extra rule.